# "Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError" error occurs in Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I updated Rails to version 3.1.0, but when I generate a new app and scaffold, it reports:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Articles#index

Showing E:/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

"\xC4\xDA" followed by "\xB2\xBF" on UTF-16LE
  (in E:/blog/app/assets/javascripts/articles.js.coffee)
```

My environment is:

- Windows XP
- Ruby1.9.2p180
- Rails 3.1.0

and the encoding of the files in the project is 'UTF-8'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the version of execjs to 1.2.4, 1.2.6 or 1.2.8 in Gemfile.lock

Only 1.2.7 will cause the problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation.

Renaming `articles.js.coffee` to `articles.js` can help.