# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Chapter 2 Section 2.2.1 A User Tour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dbmigrate

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am working through this tutorial book. I am on Windows Vista and using Cygwin. Here are the versions of the software that I am running:

Ruby version    1.9.2 (i386-cygwin)
RubyGems version    1.8.10
Rack version    1.3
Rails version   3.1.0
JavaScript Runtime  JScript
Active Record version   3.1.0
Action Pack version 3.1.0
Active Resource version 3.1.0
Action Mailer version   3.1.0
Active Support version  3.1.0

In the beginning of section 2.2, I was able to successfully run: ($ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string) and ($ rake db:migrate). But when I went to run the ($ rails server) command and opened up the webpage in Chrome, I did not see the screen shown in Fig. 2.4. But instead saw this instead: "Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Users#index" 
  I saw the post about switching the rake version from 0.9.2 to 0.8.7 and I tried this, but it didn't work for me. Does anybody now of anything else that I can try? Thank you, Nick.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484207/encodinginvalidbytesequenceerror-error-occurs-in-the-latest-rails-3-1-0) of a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried rails learning with Windows 7 + Cygwin and it was a real pain in the ass. I strongly recommend you to run linux on the virtual machine or make a dual-boot.

Comment: Thank you for the bigger picture thinking, do you recommend a certain version of Linux?

Comment: I think any distro would be good for you but Ubuntu is the one where you won't have to struggle with learning the system too.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was thinking about doing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ruby 1.9.2 you can try to add `# coding: utf-8` at the beginning of Controller file

Comment: Thank you for the post. I tried this out, but it didn't quite work for me. I ended up just getting a different error message. I'm going to go for working in Linux and see if that doesn't resolve this problem for me.