# Ruby On Rails Tutorial --> Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Folks, I am following Ruby on Rails Tutorial and working on the DemoApp  in Chapter 2. My env is :

- Win 7
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 4.0.2

Just did  the following:

```
c:\rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I brought the server up using :

```
c:\rails s
```

Now when I go try to view the users page on a web browser using the URI:
*http://"localhost":3000/users* ---> doing "localhost" instead of localhost

I get the error mentioned in the title (`Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Users#index`).

I am new to rails.
Please help?
thanks

Comment: Why are you using quotes around localhost in your URL? It makes it invalid.

Comment: Please refer the question link given. It might solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484207/encodinginvalidbytesequenceerror-error-occurs-in-rails-3-1-0

Comment: When I submited the question, i was notified by the web site to not use localhost so I enclosed it in quotes.

Comment: Sumit, i will try your suggestion and post back. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: OK good!! please try and let us know the status of your issue.

Comment: Sumit. I changed the version of execjs to 1.2.8 (it was 2.0.2) in Gemfile.lock. Did bundle install and ran the server. Went to the URL mentioned above and got this: "ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index". Any ideas? thanks

Comment: One of the most strangest problems happened. I had added a DOS key for sublime text in windows. When I did, "http://localhost:3000/users" I saw the error in server logs regarding the doskey, which didn't make sense at all.Anyway, i deleted the DOS key registry entry and now things are fine. Just for the kicks, I added the registry entry back for the doskey back but can't resproduce the problem. Aaaarsghhh. not sure if you have faced something similar.