# Ruby on Rails - Encoding Error - InvalidByteSequenceError - \xB4 on UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

Rails ver: 5.1.4

I want to link a image from 'app/assets/images/logo.png'.

File `index.html.erb`

```
<body>
    <%= link_to image_tag('logo.png') %>
</body>
```

When I run, It give me a Error: `Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError` and description show `"\xB4" on UTF-8`.
I thinks it's an Encoding error when I save file. I tried to save all of my file in UTF-8 (editor SublimeText) but it still not working. Is anyone meet same error?

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1):

You may have to give the `root_path` as well like below

```
<body>
   <%= link_to image_tag('logo.png'), root_path %>
</body>
```

Comment: can you try putting a `*.jpg` file instead and see. Also check the permissions and the size of the image. You may be right, it may be related `sublime` as well. Try using 'Notepad++' or `vim`

Answer (score 1):

I have done this like:

```
  <%=link_to image_tag('logo.png'), buildings_path %>
```

This link will display as image and will directed to given path if clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to image_url('logo.png') %>
```

Is this what you want ?

NB : `image_tag` generates an `<img>` HTML element with your image as src, thus you were trying to put an `<img>` as href of your link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `url` on click image it will be redirected though you can use give solution , and make sure you have given correct path of image `logo.png`

```
<body>
  <%=link_to your_link_path do %>
    <%=image_tag('logo.png') %>
  <%end%>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks you but still not working. I make sure path of image `logo.png` is correct. If the path don't correct, it will give an error.

Comment: Have you replaced your_path with your own path

Comment: Yeah, I have. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` add this in your `application.html.erb` in your `header` tag

Comment: its a similar question like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590314/encodinginvalidbytesequenceerror-in-homeindex-xa9-on-utf-8